# Compression artifacts on SO advert

Tags: discussion, advertising

I saw the following in a question page on Stack Overflow:

[image]

Which has compression artifact as seen when zooming:

[image]

Could this be changed? It doesn't look too good.

Comment: What are you talking about? What question? What's wrong exactly?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd can you not see the compression artifacts around the text and images? It typically happens when a picture is saved as a .jpeg instead of a web-suited format such as .png.

Comment: This would *never* have happened with a GIF.

Comment: So, this is someone's uploaded image? Or not? That is, why is this an SE bug?

Comment: @Oded Looks like a banner advert to me

Comment: @Dan - Possibly. That's why I am asking. If it is, it was not supplied by Stack Exchange, but by adzerk.

Comment: @Oded, it's a banner ad, yes. I was under the impression community ads were only shown at the side, and top-bar and inter-question ads were for non-community ads.

Comment: If it is served by Adzerk, apologies.

Comment: Banner ads are not community ads - and they are not created by Stack Exchange - definitely not a Windows 8 banner.

Comment: @tombull89 actually not, that specific ad is served by http://atlassolutions.com/ which is incorporated with Microsoft. (see the footer: *Copyright © 2013 Microsoft, Inc.*)

Comment: You're worried about the compression quality of images in an advertisement? Seriously?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes. It doesn't look professional.

Comment: No banner ads ever look professional. But in any case, these aren't StackOverflow's images in the first place. Besides, most of us don't see any ads on the network at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, granted, when I posted this question I didn't know that the ads were "farmed out" through Adzerk, I thought there was some quality control done at SE's end.

Comment: Regardless of where the ads come from, *they're still ads.* So who cares?

Comment: At the end of the day, ads are there to make you want to buy or click on something. If the ad's sloppily done, that might put people off. I thought it was an SE issue. It's not. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's an advertisement served to users with less than 200 reputation in questions tagged as [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8).

The original image used is indeed .jpg: http://cdn.atdmt.com/ds/NMMRTSMGUWDS/130405_winstore/winstore_ph3_games_728x90_static.jpg

This image is not under Stack Exchange responsibility, they just sold advertisement space to other company (Microsoft in this case) and that other company is responsible for the image and the ad contents.

This can't be changed by us, but you can "downvote" the ad so it won't show again:

> [image]